# Is there a name for this type of relation?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, terminology, relations

Let $S$ be a set. Let $\sim$ be a binary relation on $S$. Suppose $\sim$ follows these three rules.

1. $x\sim x$ for all $x\in S$ (reflexivity).
2. If $x\sim y$, then $y\sim x$ for all $x, y \in S$ (symmetry).
3. If $x_1\sim x_2 $, $x_2\sim x_3 $, $x_3\sim \cdots$, then there exists an $n>2$ in the indices of this chain of similarities such that $x_1\nsim x_n$.

I'm trying to capture kind of "partial" or "fuzzy" transitivity. I'm not sure if these are quite the right rules and I'd be happy for anyone to refine them. It reminds me of that children's game, "Whisper Down the Lane", where children in a row whisper a message into each others' ears. Eventually, the final message does not resemble the initial one at all, nor probably a few others.

Update: See comments for modifications on this definition.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

These rules seem to be inconsistent.  For example, $x\sim x\sim x\sim x\cdots$, so the third rule cannot hold in this case.

A relation that seems to meet what you want, on $\mathbb{R}$, is $D_h(x,y)$ where $xD_hy$ if and only if $|x-y|\le h$.  It doesn't meet the third condition, but it models the children's game.

Comment: What about if I say "for distinct $x_i\in S$"?

Comment: Then you would admit a lot of relations that don't capture what you want.  For example, if $S$ is finite then there will never be an infinite such chain of distinct elements from $S$ hence the third condition will always hold vacuously.

Comment: Alright, suppose I make the chain terminate at an index $n$ and say that the "breakdown" occurs for some $2<m\leq n$?

Comment: Still this doesn't capture what you want.  For example, for $n=5$, I can partition $S=\{\{1,2,3,4\}, \{5,6,7,8\},\{9,10,11,12\}\}$, and take $xRy$ if and only if $x,y$ are in the same partition.  Now there are no chains of length $5$.

Comment: Perhaps you're trying to describe [antitransitivity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intransitivity#Antitransitivity).

Comment: Antitransitivity seems too strong, right? In my example, the relation holds in many pairings in the chain. For example, $x_1\sim x_2\iff x_2\sim x_3$. Yet, this doesn't hold for $x_n$.

Comment: @Alexander: It seems that all you need is to know that transitivity fails, unless you're looking for something more precise.

Comment: Yes, I suppose this is one solution. Intuitively, I was thinking of some kind of "local transitivity" where it holds for some elements and not others. Another good example are [ring species](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_species) that can mate with their at least some of their neighbors.